# How do I prevent truncation of my Mac browser history and sync history between devices?

Tags: safari, data-synchronization, browser-history

Recently something strange happened with my Safari browsing history. Suddenly one morning `com.Apple.Safari.History` started burning CPU and a zero-byte `ClearHistoryInProgress` file appeared in `~/Library/Safari`.

Before this happened, I had history

- through 2020-01-12  on my MacBook, and
- through 2021-04-15 on my iPhone.

After this happened, I now have history

- through 2021-04-15 on my MacBook, and
- through 2021-04-15 on my iPhone.

though these two histories aren’t the same: Each appears to contain only local browsing, with no (or incomplete) syncing between devices, though in some cases I think recent items from the iPhone are synced to the MacBook, while none are synced from the MacBook to the iPhone.

I don’t know why the history on the iPhone ends on 2021-04-15, but it shouldn’t (I didn’t erase history there).

In an effort to recover from this I have repeatedly tried restoring a backup of my `History.db` through 2020-01-12 on my MacBook (after deleting all `…History…` files from `~/Library/Safari`), but eventually (some time after browsing to a new site on my iPhone?) the process repeats.

I have also tried toggling Safari use of iCloud on both devices, even deleting all iCloud info on the iPhone when I turn iCloud off there, but this has no effect.

How do I prevent my MacBook browser history from being truncated in this way? Better: how do I get the histories on both devices to sync fully through 2020-01-12 (or [whatever the history file size limit dictates](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/311143/4395))?

---

If I can get this solved, I'd then like to recover the history that has been lost from various backups of days where this occurred, but that's really a [separate follow-on question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/419084/4395).

---

UPDATE: A month later and the history on my iPhone only goes back to May 22 (a month later than reported above), while the Mac history has shortened a bit more. I understand why the Mac history is shortening (size constraints) but why is the iOS history shortening? Could it be that iOS has a smaller size limit on history, and essentially *imposes* that smaller (shorter) history on macOS if Safari history is synced in iCloud?

---

iOS 14.4.2; macOS 11.2.3; Safari 14.0.3

Comment: Just a thought: it seems like your restore process isn't going to iCloud, so the truncation is really just restoring the cloud version of the history. Might be wrong.

Comment: @EzekielElin Could be. Where can I see what the status is in iCloud?

Comment: There's nowhere specific to view that - a test would be to set up a new device, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: One thing you could try is turning off Safari sync on your Mac, completing that same restore process, then turning it back on. That might be enough to upload the restored data.